# How to use MasterDevs ChromeDevTools in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[MasterDevs ChromeDevTools](https://github.com/MasterDevs/ChromeDevTools) is a .NET Library to interact with the Chrome Developer Tools, I discovered it yesterday while searching for the efficient and simplest way to make use of the chrome websockets protocol, and I was trying to manage how can I compile a custom javascript script in the console window, but I didn't found the way to do this, because the library is giant, and the XML documentation for each member is very, very, very poor, so you can't understand the purpose of any member, and the author only provides one tiny usage example of how to use two specific commands of the thousands of commads inside the lib. So I don't get the idea how to use this library to interact with the console, to input a script in the console window, and compile it.

So I'm blind with this library, and also the official google documentation for [Runtime](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime), [Debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) or [Console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference) does not help me to find the way to compile a script in the console window...

I just want to automate the insertion of a js script in the console window, and execute it, like this:

[image]

I tried to use the `Chrome.Runtime.EnableCommand` class, then a `Chrome.Runtime.CompileScriptCommand`, but nothing happens when I try to get the resulting `CommandResponse<Chrome.Runtime.CompileScriptCommandResponse>` object (which I never get) when calling and awaiting the `IChromeSession.SendAsync()` function.

I also tried the same but using `Chrome.Debugger.EnableCommand` class and `Chrome.Debugger.SetScriptSourceCommand`, just trying for try experimenting things, because I don't know what member I should use in this library.

Well, to show what I tried with the library, in VB.NET, I just took the C# MasterDevs usage example from GitHub and tried to find the right command to compile a script:

```
Imports MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools
Imports MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.Protocol

Task.Run(
    Async Sub()

        Dim chromeProcessFactory = New ChromeProcessFactory(New StubbornDirectoryCleaner())

        Using chromeProcess As IChromeProcess = chromeProcessFactory.Create(9222, True)

            Dim sessionInfo As ChromeSessionInfo = (chromeProcess.GetSessionInfo().Result).LastOrDefault()
            Dim chromeSessionFactory = New ChromeSessionFactory()
            Dim chromeSession = chromeSessionFactory.Create(sessionInfo.WebSocketDebuggerUrl)

            Dim runtimeEnable As New Chrome.Runtime.EnableCommand
            Dim runtimeEnableResponse As CommandResponse(Of Chrome.Runtime.EnableCommandResponse) =
                Await chromeSession.SendAsync(runtimeEnable)

            Dim debuggerEnable As New Chrome.Debugger.EnableCommand
            Dim debuggerEnableResponse As CommandResponse(Of Chrome.Debugger.EnableCommandResponse) =
                Await chromeSession.SendAsync(debuggerEnable)

            Dim compileScript As New Chrome.Runtime.CompileScriptCommand
            compileScript.Expression = <script>window.open("https://www.youtube.com");</script>.Value
            Dim compileScriptResponse As CommandResponse(Of Chrome.Runtime.CompileScriptCommandResponse) =
                Await chromeSession.SendAsync(compileScript)

            Dim setScriptSource As New Chrome.Debugger.SetScriptSourceCommand()
            setScriptSource.ScriptSource = <script>window.open("https://www.google.com");</script>.Value

            Dim setScriptSourceResponse As CommandResponse(Of Chrome.Debugger.SetScriptSourceCommandResponse) =
                Await chromeSession.SendAsync(setScriptSource)

        End Using
    End Sub).Wait()
```

...note that my code is trash, because it does nothing of the expected things more than opening a new chome instance.

The reason why I'm using the `Chrome.XXXXX.EnableCommand` classes is because I found this question and its answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome-debugging-protocol/tmgIQrkr5zI and since the lack of XML documentation in MasterDevs lib, I think the `Enablecommand` classes are equivalents to what says in that answer from google groups, and because what the answer says, it seems required to use the `EnableCommand` class before nothing... but I'm really not sure whether `Chrome.Runtime.Enablecommand` class is a equivalent of `Runtime.enable`, neither whether I used it properly...

My question is:

how can I use the **MasterDevs ChromeDevTools** library in C# or VB.NET to insert a js code snippet in the Chrome's console window and then execute it?.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the project needs to be updated.

On the project's github page, the owner mentioned you may need to re-build the source using the new protocol.json from the Chrome team.  (https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/)  That file was updated as recently as April 9, 2018 but the latest version of MasterDevs/ChromeDevTools on Nuget and their last passing build commit is from November 3, 2017.  It's likely that the latest version of Chrome may have broken the latest version of MasterDevs/ChromeDevTools.

Currently at the time I wrote this the MasterDevs/ChromeDevTools project build is failing, you may be able to grab an older version and update it with the current protocol.json file and re-build it.  I would ask any further questions in the Issues section on the github project page.

Comment: I forgot to mention, every call I tried to make on the current Nuget build (1.1.0) failed for me with a Internal Server Error (500).